# Field Service Lightning to track location and to auto change the status of the schedule appointment to Done

Tags: field-service-lightning, fieldservice

A user goes to a scheduled appointment. He changes the status to arrived. When the user leaves the location, track his location and when they leave the location - auto change the status of the schedule appointment to Done.

How can we do this...